How to fill this hole under the floor vinyl plank?
Under the floor vinyl plank in our basement, we have a hole. We have tape and a heavy rug over it now (both removed for these photos), and it's... okay. But it's something I'd like to fix.
Is it possible to fill this without removing the planks? E.g. filling it with an expanding foam that hardens?







The big question is,  How did this happen?"  Did you buy the house and then after time find this?  It is not common for a hole to just open up under any flooring.

It looks like there an access opening for something under there,  if you fill this space with concrete you may regret it later. or maybe it's an old floor safe and you're missing out on a treasure.

It's clearly a constructed access to something, and should have an access into it in the floor, rather than being concealed under it, much less filled in any way, unless you can determine (for certain) that it's for some outdated purpose that really and truly no longer applies. Plugging it now might mean a future plumbers bill becomes 10 or 100 times larger, for instance.

We definitely did not see that hole there when redid the flooring ~14 years ago. So this hole was a relatively recent development. It's possible the hole developed over time, or it's possible was always there but there was a thin sheet of concrete-like substance (?) covering it? We may fill it with bricks and then lay vinyl plank over it. It doesn't need to be perfect, and that will give us flexibility to access it if we need to in the future (vs. filling it with mortar).
The building itself used to be a restaurant, maybe that's access to the grease trap?


Remove the vinyl planks surrounding hole to determine the size of the hole.
Using a grinder, create a lip around the hole of about 3/4 x 3/4".
Take a piece of Exterior grade 5/8" plywood and cut to the size of the lipped opening.
Relay your planks over the covered hole, noting the boundaries of your plywood piece.
Remove and cut the planks with a sharp knife to suit the size of your cover. Glue them to the cover.
Relay the remaining planks around the cover.

You will need new planking to complete the job.

Step 2, using a grinder: would this mean basically shaving out foundation/concrete to create that 3/4" wide by 5/8" deep lip? And I assume you mean an angle grinder?

Yes. The problem is maintaining the existing floor level while providing support for the flooring over the hole. Vinyl plank in typically +/- 3/16" thick. You'd be quite the artist to grind bang on the first time.

I'm a bit confused. Is that vinyl coming off of the plank? It's not sheet vinyl correct? If you're looking for a "good enough" solution, the void underneath seems shallow. Can you put some mortar down there with a weight over and across the loose piece of vinyl so that it will dry flat? That won't hold to the vinyl, but it would give you a solid surface to use an adhesive to hold it down and flat.
If it were my home, I'd be wondering why the hole is there. Was it created over time? Or did the original floor layer put down that plank over a gap in the floor?

We definitely did not see that hole there when redid the flooring ~14 years ago. So this hole was a relatively recent development. It's possible the hole developed over time, or it's possible was always there but there was a thin sheet of concrete-like substance (?) covering it?
We may fill it with bricks and then lay vinyl plank over it. It doesn't need to be perfect, and that will give us flexibility to access it if we need to in the future (vs. filling it with mortar).

The picture clearly shows that a mortar overlayment was applied prior to the original floor installation. I would not be surprised if it was some dense cardboard covering the opening and leveling compound poured on top.

You should not be asking questions in an answer. If you're asking rhetorically, maybe state your assumptions directly.
